# Autowiring a bean in a library that autowires a bean in another library

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have an object of a class `JwtApplicationTokenProvider` I am injecting into my constructor:

```
private final JwtApplicationTokenProvider jwtApplicationTokenProvider;

@Autowired
public ClientPerformanceAnalyticsController(JwtApplicationTokenProvider jwtApplicationTokenProvider) {
    this.jwtApplicationTokenProvider = jwtApplicationTokenProvider;
}
```

This class is part of a library I have imported via Maven and is fully qualified as `com.garbage.mantis.jwt.application.JwtApplicationTokenProvider`. In order to inform Spring of this bean I have added the package to `@ComponentScan` as so:

`@ComponentScan({"com.garbage.wt.igip.gateway", "com.iggroup.mantis.jwt.application"})`

When I try to run the application it fails with the error:

```
Field jwtApplicationTokenGenerator in com.garbage.mantis.jwt.application.configuration.JwtApplicationTokenGenerationConfiguration required a bean of type 'com.garbage.mantis.jwt.application.JwtApplicationTokenGenerator' that could not be found.
```

I can see this class does indeed exist but in another package in another library: 
`com.garbage.mantis.jwt.application.JwtApplicationTokenGenerator` so when I try to add the package to the `@ComponentScan` list of arguments it fails with the same error:

`@ComponentScan({"com.garbage.wt.igip.gateway", "com.garbage.mantis.jwt.application", "com.garbage.mantis.jwt.application.configuration"})`

```
Field jwtApplicationTokenGenerator in com.iggroup.mantis.jwt.application.configuration.JwtApplicationTokenGenerationConfiguration required a bean of type 'com.iggroup.mantis.jwt.application.JwtApplicationTokenGenerator' that could not be found.
```

I have another application I have cloned which implements this and it runs without issue but I am unable to find what they have done to enable this. They don't even seem to pass the base packages in their `@ComponentScan` arguments.

What am I missing?

Comment: The fact that you add a `@ComponentScan` doesn't make objects in that package add an `@Component` (or spezialized annotation for that matter). So if the `JwtApplicationTokenGenerator` is't annotated it won't be detected.

Comment: Spring does not create a bean for 3rd party libraries, for `@ComponentScan` it does not guarantee the same.
You need to use `@Bean` annotation, create an object and this would push your bean to the container Or else extend the `JwtApplicationTokenProvider` class